# Gitlab-CI error upon deploying Docker Image on swarm mode

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Hi i have problem with updating / changing image of my service on the server running Docker swarm mode.
Here is the process of manually updating the service.

1. push the project to gitlab from local machine.
2. pull the project from gitlab in server.
3. build a Docker image as `my-project:latest`
4. tag `my-project:latest` as `registry.gitlab.com/my-group/my-project:staging`
5. i push the image using `docker push registry.gitlab.com/my-group/my-project:staging`
6. i run `docker stack deploy -c ~/docker-stack.yml api --with-registry-auth`
   and it works fine.

However if i move the codes above into a `gitlab-ci.yml` despite of ending the job successfully i get an error when it is trying to update the service.

```
Updating service api_backend (id: r4gqmil66kehzf0oehzqk57on)
 image registry.gitlab.com/my-group/my-project:staging could not be accessed on a registry to record
 its digest. Each node will access registry.gitlab.com/my-group/my-project:staging independently,
 possibly leading to different nodes running different
 versions of the image.
```

Also the gitlab runner is executing commands in `Shell` mode.
I have tried different solutions as you can see i'm even using the `--with-registry-auth` flag.

To summarize this:
everything works fine if i enter the codes manually but i get an error when i use `gitlab-ci.yml`.

Comment: If still relevant,  could you try to add a sleep action after the deploy so the runner is still around when the docker is doing the actual pull ? (pasting your actual CI file would also help)